# What's the idiomatic way to move a go binary into a pod before helm install?

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, circleci

I use CircleCI to build a go binary that I want to run in a pod installed by Helm charts. I want to move the binary from CircleCI to the remote cluster so it's available when the pod starts. I know it's possible with volumes, like ConfigMap or Secrets but I'm not sure what the best way to do this.

I once made it work with a private docker registry and a kubernetes Secrets for the credentials of the registry but I don't like this option. I don't want to have to build and push a new docker image on every binary change.

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/golang:1.12.7
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: go get -v -t -d ./...
      - run: go build cmd/main.go
      - run: ...
      - run: helm install

workflows:
  version: 2
  build:
    jobs:
      - build_and_deploy:
```

The expected result should be a new binary available on the cluster every time the job runs.

Comment: Since only go binary is changing - only that layer will be downloaded - and not other layers of the container - I think a container image is a clean option!

Comment: creating a container image is the common way to do this.

Comment: The idiomatic way is to put the binary in your docker image that helm installs.

Comment: "I don't want to have to build and push a new docker image on every binary change." -- Why not? That is precisely what helm is designed for.

Comment: @Flimzy because it brings the complexity of a private docker registry.

Comment: That's part of the complexity inherent in using helm. It's also not very complex at all.

Answer (score 1):

According to the best practices - the binary file should be applied during your build image execution - as mentioned by community above and [best developer practices](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/02/24/10-things-to-avoid-in-docker-containers/):

> Don’t create images from running containers – In other terms, don’t use “docker commit” to create an image. This method to create an image is not reproducible  and should be completely avoided. Always use a Dockerfile or any other S2I (source-to-image) approach that is totally reproducible, and you can track changes to the Dockerfile if you store it in a source control repository (git).

However, from another point of view you can consider:

**1**. [init contianers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) to build your image directly on the cluster

**2**. [kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko) with with external location of your build context (gcs bucket git repository)

**3**. helm pre-install hook in order to use the above mentioned solutions

**4**. finally other solutions like [cloud build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-docker#preparing_source_files)  or [cloud build locally](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-debug-locally)

Please refer also to "[Switching from CircleCI to Google Cloud Build](https://itnext.io/what-i-learned-switching-from-circleci-to-google-cloud-build-b4405de2be38)". 
As described in the article above you can use [keel](https://keel.sh/docs/#helm-example)  to automatically update your deployments when the image in the docker repository is updated.

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: It does help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your CI/CD should simply build a Docker container with that binary. Then you should push it to the private repository. Cluster should download the binary.